# Importing CRUD module in Play! 1.2.3

Tags: playframework, crud

When I import the CRUD module using the **dependencies.yml** like so:

```
require:
    - play
    - play -> crud
    - play -> secure
```

I get a Compilation error: CRUD can't be resolved to a type.

But when I do it the depreciated way, by adding:

```
module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud
```

To the application.conf it works, but play! says adding the module via the application.conf is depreciated and I should rather do it via the dependencies.yml

Any Ideas as to why I can't import the module the recommended way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run `play dependencies` on your app. See [Dependency management section of Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/dependency).

Answer (score 3):

This is because your eclipse project has a wrong classpath. After
enabling a new module for your project, you need to run the
'eclipsify' command again in order to generate a new .classpath file
for your eclipse project. If eclipse does not reload it properly, try
to remove it from the workspace and re-import it again.

Comment: The same problem I had in Idea, but command `play idealize` helps.